# ALTER data type for all tables in db MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqldatatypes

I want to convert all DATETIME columns in my db to DATETIME(6).  Is there one command that I can I use to do this?  I have a lot of tables and curious if there is a quick method.

Something that would do this logic

```
FOR T IN TABLES ALTER TABLE T MODIFY ALL DATETIME TO DATETIME(6)
```

Answer (score -1):

if u are using my sql server, u can use an undocumented stored procedure to do this

```
EXEC ms_foreachtable 'ALTER TABLE [?] .....'
```

Replace table name with ? in statement

Comment: I'm using MySQL Server.  Where is this command ran? In sql or shell? If shell I don't see ms_foreachtable command.  If sql